# How to set CSS style property in JavaScript with fallback?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In CSS, I have e.g. the following:

```
background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"); /* fallback */
background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"), linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531); /* W3C */
```

I want to achieve the same effect in JavaScript. I.e. I want to set the backgroundImage property, but I also want to set a fallback. But element.style.backgroundImage does not accept a string array.

```
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("IMAGE_URL"), linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531)'; // How to include the fallback here?
```

I don't want to use hacks to check which browser the user is using. If it's not possible, I would also like to know.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to set it in JavaScript? Is adding or removing a class an option? Are you targeting old browsers?

Comment: Inline css does not support inline fallback. Try adding class to element and then write CSS with JS, or simply have pre-written CSS

Answer (score 1):

Just append a `<style>` element using JavaScript, and insert the CSS you would have used that way:

```js
document.head.innerHTML += `
<style>
    element {
        background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"); /* fallback */
        background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"), linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531); /* W3C */
    }
</style>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use CSS.supports and find the first item in an array of values that returns true. Then apply that to style.

Note: not all properties can be detected - notably whether flex gap is supported. Flex box gap is recent but grid gap has been there a while so testing for ‘gap’ is ambiguous.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports

This is effectively what the browser is doing when you provide a list.